# Confusion with range and with_items nested loops in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have this play book that works fine ...

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    repo_top: "."
    cluster: "ab01"
    stype: "xyz"
    start_zone: 10
    end_zone: 130
    sym_link_dests:
      - "../zones_foo/agent"
      - "../zones_bar/collaborate_zones"

  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: mkdir group_vars dir
      file:
        path: "{{ repo_top }}/group_vars/{{ cluster }}_oo_{{ stype }}{{ item }}"
        state: directory
      loop: "{{ range(start_zone, end_zone)|list}}"

    - name: Make symlink for ../zones_foo/agent
      shell:
        cmd: "ln -s ../zones_foo/agent"
        chdir: "{{ repo_top }}/group_vars/{{ cluster }}_oo_{{ stype }}{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ range(start_zone, end_zone)|list}}"

    - name: Make symlink for ../zones_bar/collaborate_zones
      shell:
        cmd: "ln -s ../zones_bar/collaborate_zones"
        chdir: "{{ repo_top }}/group_vars/{{ cluster }}_oo_{{ stype }}{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ range(start_zone, end_zone)|list}}"
```

... but I found out that the 'sym_link_dests' list will be growing by 100 or so items.
And I am not sure how to go about creating a nested loop.  I do not seem to be able to find any examples where the out loop is a `range` and the second is `with_items`.  ANy help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my comment on your self-answer, here is a way to acheive the same result:

1. using the `product` filter in a `loop:` stanza (same functionnality as `with_nested` in the new generation syntax).
2. using the `file` module instead of shell. The trick here is that you must provide a name in the `path` that points to the exact file you want to create. You can easily get this with the `basename` filter. After that, things are easy as the `src` attribute accepts a relative path to the file being created.

```yaml
    - name: Make symlinks
      file:
        path: "{{ repo_top }}/group_vars/{{ cluster }}_oo_{{ stype }}{{ item.0 }}/{{ item.1 | basename }}"
        src: "{{ item.1 }}"
        state: link
      loop: "{{ range(start_zone, end_zone) | list | product(sym_link_dests) }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was straight forward.  I don't know why I was having such a hard time:

```yaml
    - name: Make symlinks
      shell:
        cmd: "ln -s {{ item[1] }}"
        chdir: "{{ repo_top }}/group_vars/{{ cluster }}_oo_{{ stype }}{{ item[0] }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ range(start_zone, end_zone)|list}}"
        - '{{ sym_link_dests }}'
```

Comment: Using `file` instead of `shell` to respect good practice (i e. use a dedicated module when it exists) would make this the perfect answer.

Comment: @Zeitounator I tried to use the file module but couldn't figure out how to use it for relative path symlink `mylink -> ../some_other_dir/myfile`.